# How can I add a context menu for recycle bin

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-7, windows-shell

How can I manage to add a context menu for windows recycle bin? And how could I eventually access the files within? I know Recycle bin is a virtual folder and that it has a tree-like structure, do I have to go all the way to access the files within?

**edited:**

```
HKLM
{
NoRemove Software
{
    NoRemove Classes 
    {
        NoRemove CLSID
        {
            NoRemove {645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}
            {
                NoRemove shellex
                {
                    NoRemove ContextMenuHandlers
                    {
                        ForceRemove {FC944A65-4422-4A2C-B867-1BA01318A944}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }      
   }
}
```

Comment: If you need all the files, then yes you need to enumerate them. Being a virtual folder doesn't change anything. If you need just one file, then which one?

Comment: I need all the files that appear in the recycle bin, but how can I register a context menu for it?

Comment: Don't register your Shell Extension to `HKCR` directly like that.  Use `HKCU\Software\Classes` and/or `HKLM\Software\Classes` instead.  Since `HKCR` is a merged view of multiple Registry keys, it should only be used for reading data, not for writing data.

Comment: How about now? I've edited it again.

Comment: and anyway on the msdn pages they go str8 for the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID and it does work for other file types extensions.

Comment: @A.K Is in your question posted the last version of registering shell extension for RecycleBin? Also, how do you determine if selected folder is RecycleBin in `IShellExtInit::Initialize` and/or `IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the following Registry keys:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\Shell
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\ShellEx
```

For what you are attempting, you will likely have to write a Context Menu Shell Extension and register it in the `ShellEx` key.

[Creating Shell Extension Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144067.aspx)

[Creating Shortcut Menu Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171.aspx)

Comment: man, I'll post my code for registering the dll, I look in the registry and it is there, but the context menu doesn't show up on the recycle bin, the context menu appears on other files that I have registered it to (like .txt files).