# Debugging a shell extension in release mode

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc, windows-shell

I have a shell extension that I build in release mode, I also generate debug symbols and .pdb files. I attach the visual studio program that builds the context menu extension .dll file to the running explorer.exe process, I can see  in the output window while the program is attached explorer process events, like the following:

```
'explorer.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mydocs.dll'
'explorer.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sendmail.dll'
'explorer.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\zipfldr.dll'
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x16d8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1650) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1070) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

But it never reaches the breakpoints that I have set in the function Initialize (form the class that inherits and implements the IshellExtInit class). When I do a right click on a file, the right click menu initialises with the custom context menu and performs desired actions, but no breakpoint hitting involved!!
I want to know how can I debug because I'm trying to register the context menu for the recycle bin and it doesn't work, I want to see what's happening with the code.
The code for registration with the Recycle Bin can be found on this post:
[recycle bin registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057270/how-can-i-add-a-context-menu-for-recycle-bin)

Comment: Debugging release builds is notoriously inaccurate, and isn't much improved even with symbols. You might try windbg, ida, or VS' assembly mode; those will pay attention to breakpoints, but you obviously are working in assembly.

Comment: Agreed. Although if you enable symbols and remove all optimizations from the release build you may be able to work with its limitations.

Comment: If i build in Debug Mode i get this:  error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Performing registration" . I am running VS as admin.

Comment: Your custom build step is wrong, check your settings in debug configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try manually registering your debug build using regsvr32, e.g.

```
regsvr32 mydocs.dll
```

You may have to kill Explorer to get it to recognize the registry changes.

If that doesn't work you could try throwing up a message box in your extension to see if that'll stop Explorer long enough for you to debug into your extension.